# How to inspect asp.net core methods?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC application with individual user accounts authentication. I would like to see how they implemented some methods. I suppose I can do it since ASP.NET Core is open source project, but I can't find these methods in github repository.

```
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/
```

I am highly interested in this method.

```
https://localhost:portnumber/Identity/Account/Login
```

**Q1: How to find this method in my project and is it possible to debug it?**

**Q2: Why I dont see AccountController file in my new created app?**

[image: missing files]

**ANSWER:**
It turned out, that from .net core 2.2 version if you want to see or change Identity controllers, you have to scaffold them manually.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods you are referring to are part of your application. Have a look under the **Areas** folder. There should be a subfolder called **Identity**. Under the Identity folder, you should find the `AccountController` and your `Login` action method should be inside this controller.

If you really want to look into the source code you need to have a look at the [SignInManager.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs) class and see how the SignInAsync method is implemented, which is used by the `Login` action method.

**EDIT**

Please refer to the screenshot below

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Structure for the newly created app using Web Application template

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is only one file in Areas folder. 
Areas/Identity/Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml

Comment: Which template did you use to create your Asp.Net Core application? It seems like it's using the Asp.Net Core Razor Pages feature. Do you see the Pages folder in the Solution Explorer? If not, please see what's inside `_ViewStart.cshtml` file. It should look something like `@{ Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}`

Comment: I do not see Pages folder. Where can I download proper template?

Comment: You don't need to download the templates. What I meant is when you created your Asp.Net Core application, which template did you select from the dialogue that looks like the screenshot I have attached. If you selected the web application, then you would have Razor Pages feature. If you had selected Web Application with MVC then you will see the controllers. Also, please note that Razor pages is a controller-less approach. To learn more about it, please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I know what you meant. I created both web application and web application mvc. None of these have controllers we are interested in. Inside _ViewStart.cshtml there is a line 
@{ Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}

Comment: That's strange. According to `_ViewStart.cshtml` you should have a **Pages** folder at the same level as **Views**. Also, are you saying that when you create MVC application, you don't see the controllers either? In that case, I would suggest you reinstall the Asp.Net Core framework and perform the repair.

Comment: Could you provide a screen presenting structure (especially pages folder) of newly created app?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot to the answer. Let's have a chat otherwise at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807277/how-to-inspect-asp-net-core-methods/55807962

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192267/discussion-between-justme-and-shahzad-hassan).