# Asp.Net core Individual User Authentication Login/Register Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to Asp.net core razor pages. I am using asp .net core version 2.2, I am trying to make an application using Social Media authentication services. But the problem I am facing is the weird structure of asp .net core razor applications. I have already done the authentication things, but the problem I am facing is to find the Login and Registration pages. Where can we find them? What if we want to change the layout or something. What should we do for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inspect asp.net core methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807277/how-to-inspect-asp-net-core-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you implemented authorization, and based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) :

You should be able to find the scaffolded views in the `Areas\Identity`'s folder of your project or in the `~/Pages/` folder.

If you want to change the layout or something else, you can edit those views (customize) and/or create other ones.

Don't forget to generate the scaffolded views using :

> From Solution Explorer, right-click on the project > Add > New Scaffolded Item

Hope it helps.

Comment: The only files I have in ```Areas/Identity/Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml``` there is no login or registration page

Comment: Identity is implemented as Razor Class Library, so you won't see the Login/Register pages. However, you can scaffold them and modify as needed. Have a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081181/how-we-can-access-the-account-controller-and-its-views-inside-asp-net-core-proje#comment98810599_56081181) and this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project)

Comment: Based on "I have done the authentication things" I thought you already have scaffolded your views. I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: I tried it and have my login and registration pages, but the same application is now giving me an error of
```HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure```

Answer (score 0):

The default scaffolded Razor pages in ASP.NET Core are made using Partial Views. The default layout of the applicaton can be found in `Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.

Inside of this file there is a reference to `Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml` , which contains the layout for the login page. The reference should be somewhere around line 35 in the `_Layout.cshtml`.

If you want to edit the way the default Razor pages look, this is where you do it.